# ClassCastException when unmarshalling JSON

Tags: java, json, unmarshalling

I have the following xml entity:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class DocumentDossier {

    private XdsJsonSubmissionSet submissionSet;
    private XdsJsonDocument documentEntry;
    private List<XdsJsonFolder> folder;
    private List<XdsJsonAssociation> association;
    ...
```

And I'm trying to unmarshall a JSON file in the following way:

```
    String content = IOUtils.toString(is);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(content);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    MappedNamespaceConvention con = new MappedNamespaceConvention(config);
    XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj, con);

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(DocumentDossier.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    DocumentDossier result = (DocumentDossier) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader);
```

But the JSON I need to unmarshall doesn't have a root node, and that's the way it's supposed to be. Here's the JSON in question:

```
{
    "submissionSet":    {...},
    "documentEntry":    {...},
    "association":    {...}
}
```

Using this code, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: XdsJsonSubmissionSet cannot be cast to DocumentDossier
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: There is an implied root node (the outer `{}` are in fact a JSON "object") and you need that to map its elements to fields in `DocumentDossier`. So this should already work as is. Do you get an error? Or what specifically do you want to skip?

Comment: I get the following error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: XdsJsonSubmissionSet cannot be cast to DocumentDossier

What I want to skip is having my JSON object wrapped in {"documentDossier": ... }, so my web service will be able to receive JSON objects like the one I posted.

Comment: If you would wrap your JSON with `{"documentDossier":...}`, you would need another Java class that wraps `DocumentDossier` in order to be able to parse the JSON. The JSON above should already map to `DocumentDossier` as it is. The error must have a different reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `@XmlElement` to each field.

Also don't forget to add `@XmlRootElement` to `XdsJsonSubmissionSet`, and `@XmlElement` to its fields.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me, instead I decided to pass the JSON to my code as an InputStream and wrap it in a "documentDossier":{...}. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This wrapping is absolutely unnecessary. did you try which output you get when you marshal a `DocumentDossier`?